# How to clip left content using overflow-x: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to clip content from left using overflow-x:hidden. By default its clipping content from right. I want the content to grow from left and as soon as it hits the parent boundary it should clip content from left instead of right. Any idea? Below is the current problem i am facing.

```
div {
height: 120px;
background: #666;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LxYGN/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your css. It will cause the text to flow right to left and subsequently hide the overflow on the left:

```
direction: rtl;
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/direction

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
div > * {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LxYGN/6/

Comment: hmm thanks for your reply. Actually the problem is that my content will grow from left to right, which means that its float: left. When the content is grown that much that when it overflow from the right end of parent it should clip content from left. 
Expected solution: When it starts overlapping from right edge of parent, at that time i have to change its float value to float: right so that it clips the content from left. If some one have better solution please share :)